# Interceptar información generada por lector de código de barras en Java

Tags: javascript, java, html

Necesito interceptar la información que se obtiene desde un lector de código de barras, para de esta manera guardarlo en variables y presentarlo en una pantalla con diferentes campos: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado, pero siempre se retorna la información en donde sé encuentra el focus del mouse, pienso que debería haber un paso previo para ello, de tal manera que se pueda hacer un split de toda la información para luego colocarla en donde corresponde.

Comment: Con JS puedes hacer una función para hacer el split según tus criterios, y después mandar cada una de las variables a su correspondiente input, podría ser por id para que tengas el control.

Comment: Java o JavaScript? No son los mismos lenguajes...

Comment: tendrias que hacer el uso del Puerto COM para detectar porque puerto pasaran los datos

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve una situación similar hace tiempo y la solucioné de la siguiente forma (lo hice en Javascript pues era una aplicación web):

La mayoría de los lectores permiten configurar un carácter (o cadena de caracteres) como prefijo a la entrada que lee. De ese modo, y teniendo en cuenta que un lector de código de barras no es más que un teclado, se trata de capturar los eventos (keyups, por ejemplo) en todo el documento y comprobar si se introduce dicho carácter (o cadena de caracteres). En el momento que esto ocurre (se ha detectado la cadena concreta), tenemos dos opciones:

1. Mover el focus() al campo que nos interesa y que sea ahí donde "caigan" el resto de caracteres.
2. Seguir leyendo las entradas hasta recibir el "intro" y, entonces, copiar la cadena recibida (eliminando el prefijo) en el campo de nuestro interés. También podemos enviar dicha cadena a una función para su tratamiento previo, si es nuestro objetivo.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Saludos @Hnry23, gracias por tu aporte en SOes, solo una recomendación, para responder asegúrate de que la pregunte se ajuste a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ya que muchas de las preguntas que no se ajustan a esto simplemente terminan cerradas o incluso eliminadas haciendo que tu esfuerzo sea envano. Bienvenido a la comunidad. ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, Israel! Tienes razón. Lo tendré en cuenta a partir de ahora.